# is there an AutoMapper merge function?

Tags: automapper

AutoMapper Beginner Question:
  I was hoping AutoMapper would let me merge properties from a DTO back into an existing business object.  I don't see anything like that.  AutoMapper.Map() generates a new object and populates it, but I need to copy DTO changes back into the original business object.
  Is there an Map function that takes a source and target object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Map method is overloaded. You can use Map(src, dst).

Comment: I'm not quite sure this answers the question in the title of this post since what it does is override the properties in the destination object - but no merge them.